# Weighted average of areas within zones

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, geometry, arcgis-10.5, calculate-values

I have a fishnet that defines my zones for my analysis, and am interested in the area of different hydrologic soil groups (A, B, C, D) within these zones. Each soil group has a corresponding score (1, 0.65, 0.3, 0.05). I want to calculate a weighted average of the soil group scores for each zone. How do I go about doing this?

[Soil groups within zones in watershed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10zF5.jpg)

[image: Table with Fishnet ID (FID_CarpWS_FishNet), Soil Group (hydgrpcdc), and the Score for each group (Soil_Score)]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to start by creating two fields in your initial fishnet dataset.

Call the fields `Fisharea` in the fishnet. Calculate the area of the fishnet in this field. This is the initial area. Next create a field called `FishID` and give each fishnet polygon a unique ID.

Next run the **intersect** tool between the fishnet and soils layer. Create a field called `FSoilArea`. Calculate the area of the polygons in your intersected layer.

Create a new field called `Weight`. Take the newly calculated `FSoilArea` and divide it by the `Fisharea` field. This is the proportion of the soil layer in the fishnet.

Next create a new field called `WSoilIndex`. Multiply the `Weight` field into the field containing the soil index values.

Take the intersected layer and run the **dissolve** tool. Select `FishID` and `Soil Type` as the dissolve fields. Under the Statistics options select the `WSoilIndex` as the input and Sum as operation.

You will now have a Fishnet with the soil indices weighted by area.

Comment: Thanks! Why choose sum as the operation and not mean?

Comment: I guess average would work too. Sorry re-reading the question I see you not looking for the weighted score value. Averaging it up should work.